# What's the best way to implement 3D convolution in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

It seems the current version of Tensorflow doesn't support any command to directly perform 3D convolution. Theano does so, but I don't want to switch to Theano. I was just wondering is there any simple way to perform 3D convolution by perhaps using the available commands like conv2d? If anybody has the code to share, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, 3d convolution was added at the beginning of March.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/2213#issuecomment-217081951

See commit: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/6a187ccddaebb741ea77fc3201c6e36625f0aadb